# Can I use HTML to create and email with a subject which is the page title?

Tags: html, email

I'm aware that I can create an email link with the subject being a set piece of text, but I was wondering if I could use things specified in the `head` and `meta` tags, such as `title` or `description` or `author` etc., in the email subject?

```
<a href="mailto:name@domain.com?subject=The subject of the mail">Email</a>
```

How would I modify if I wanted to do this?

### Edit:

I'll be using a macro or other program to create each HTML file (they're reports) so it's not a huge problem if this isn't possible. I'll have the macro change that line of code each time.

Comment: It's not possible, without using javascript.

Answer (score 1):

According to [specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2368) you cannot:

> The special hname "body" indicates that the associated hvalue is
> the    body of the message. The "body" hname should contain the
> content for    the first text/plain body part of the message. The
> mailto URL is    primarily intended for generation of short text
> messages that are    actually the content of automatic processing
> (such as "subscribe"    messages for mailing lists), not general MIME
> bodies.

Comment: Thanks for the descriptive reply!  I thought as much, but figured I may as well check before ruling it out completely

Answer (score -1):

You will have to have your macro or program change that line each time. There's no way to link to the content of meta tags, except maybe to get a piece of JavaScript to change the link target on each page.